# AWK & Bash: Checking that a User's Home is Owned by the User

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm trying to cycle through /etc/passwd with a single-line command in order to find those users who have a home directory which is not owned by the user.

The following has syntax errors in it, but hopefully illustrates the concept.

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{nores=1;} {if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 0 && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" && $(system( "ls -ld $6 | awk \'{print $3}\')" ) != $1 ) {print "The directory " $6 " exists for user " $1 " but is not owned by that user"; nores=0 }} END{if (nores) print "No results";}' /etc/passwd
```

This is associated with writing checks for the CIS RHEL6 Benchmark item 9.1.13 for some internal testing.

Solution I will likely use, which helped fix what I did wrong:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN { FS = ":"; nores = 1; } { if ((system("[ -d " $6 " ]") == 0) && ($7 != "/sbin/nologin")) { "stat -c \"%U\" " $6 | getline s; if (s != $1) { print "The directory " $6 " exists for user " $1 " but is not owned by that user"; nores = 0 } } } END { if (nores) print "No results"; }' /etc/passwd
```

Other solution, but making it fit the requirements by putting it on one line::

```
flag=0; testuser=$(stat "/home/testuser" -c %U); while IFS=':' read -r myuser a b c d mydir e; do if [ -d "$mydir" -a "$e" != "/sbin/nologin" ]; then if [ "$myuser" != "$testuser" -a "$myuser" != $(stat "$mydir" -c %U) ]; then echo "The directory $mydir exists for user $myuser but is not owned by that user"; flag=1; fi fi done </etc/passwd; if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then echo "No results"; fi
```

Comment: One liners quickly become hard to read. That is why you place them is a shell script with proper indentation. As an adding bonus you call the shell script by name instead of typing hundreds of characters.

Comment: You should use `getent` instead of parsing `/etc/password`.

Comment: @fd0 You're assuming this is being called by a person at the command-line. In actuality this is being called by a tool that requires it all be on one-line, hence the requirement. No would would argue that properly indented code is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or your `awk` could be:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN { FS = ":"; nores = 1; } { if ((system("[ -d " $6 " ]") == 0) && ($7 != "/sbin/nologin")) { "stat -c \"%U\" " $6 | getline s; if (s != $1) { print "The directory " $6 " exists for user " $1 " but is not owned by that user"; nores = 0 } } } END { if (nores) print "No results"; }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Man, I tried something along that syntax before and couldn't get it to work, but your code definitely works. This is technically much closer to what I was trying to, so going to accept.

Comment: Don't hurry to accept, Costas solutions is very good, consider it. I just tried doing it as per your `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

```
flag=0
testuser=$(stat "/home/testuser" -c %U)
while IFS=':' read -r myuser a b c d mydir e
do
    if [ -d "$mydir" -a "$e" != "/sbin/nologin" ]
    then
        if [ "$myuser" != "$testuser" -a \
             "$myuser" != $(stat "$mydir" -c %U) ] 
        then
            echo "The directory $mydir exists for user $myuser" \
                 "but is not owned by that user"
            flag=1
        fi
    fi
done </etc/passwd
if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No results"
fi
```

Comment: Thank-you. This is very different to what I was doing, but it works!
In case someone else needs it on oneline, here is the same thing:
flag=0; testuser=$(stat "/home/testuser" -c %U); while IFS=':' read -r myuser a b c d mydir e; do if [ -d "$mydir" -a "$e" != "/sbin/nologin" ]; then if [ "$myuser" != "$testuser" -a "$myuser" != $(stat "$mydir" -c %U) ]; then echo "The directory $mydir exists for user $myuser but is not owned by that user"; flag=1; fi fi done </etc/passwd; if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then echo "No results"; fi

Answer (score 2):

With

```
perl -F: -anE 'if( (stat $F[5])[4] != $F[2] )
                   { say "$F[0]($F[2]) not own $F[5]" }' /etc/passwd
```

you get almost what you wanted. In /etc/passwd:

- F0 = username
- F5 = home
- F2 = uid
- `stat FileOrDir [4]` is the uid of FileOrDir

Add some more condition to tune it. Example:

```
perl -F: -anE 'if( -d $F[5]  and               # F5 is a directory and
                   (stat $F[5])[4] != $F[2]    # owner(home) isNot uid
                 ) { say ...
```